# Stata using if condition with _n under by and egen commands

Tags: stata

In Stata's auto data the following command creates all missing values: why?

```
bysort mpg: egen n1 = mean(price) if rep78[_n]!=rep78
```

For example take the 14 mpg group:

```
 price  mpg rep78
11385   14  3
14500   14  2
6303    14  4
12990   14  
5379    14  4
13466   14  3
```

I expected that `n1` for the first row will be mean(14500,6303,12990,5379). Basically I want the mean after excluding the first and last rows because for them we have `rep78[_n]==rep78` (equals 3). But instead, I get all  missing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscript `[_n]` is harmless but vacuous here as referring to the current observation. So the condition is just equivalent to `rep78 != rep78` or `rep78[_n] != rep78[_n]` -- which is never true and so no observations satisfy the condition and the mean is returned as missing.

You're hoping or imagining that the prefix `by:` implies comparisons within a group, but at best that works only if subscripts are explicit and different.

This works for your problem:

```
sysuse auto, clear 

gen wanted = . 

quietly forval i = 1/`=_N' { 
    su price if mpg == mpg[`i'] & rep78 != rep78[`i'], meanonly 
    replace wanted = r(mean) in `i'
}
```

There may be a way to do this with `rangestat` or `rangerun` from SSC, or otherwise, in which case a better solution may follow.

EDIT: The OP's code suggestion in comments

```
bysort mpg rep78: egen sum_m_r_price = sum(price)
bysort mpg rep78: egen count_m_r_price = count(price)
bysort mpg: egen sum_r_price = sum(price) 
bysort mpg: egen count_r_price = count(price) 
gen b_wanted = ( sum_r_price-sum_m_r_price)/ (count_r_price-count_m_r_price)
```

appears equivalent.

In reverse, this should be faster than that:

```
rangestat (sum) sum2=price (count) count2=price, i(rep78 0 0) by(mpg)
rangestat (sum) sum1=price (count) count1=price, i(mpg 0 0)
gen double wanted = (sum1 - sum2) / (count1 - count2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this works, but seems extremely slow on my dataset with 1.26 million rows!

Comment: Observations is the Stata terms, not rows. I haven't thought of a faster method yet: other things to think about on 25 December.

Comment: Happy Christmas! Thanks for still being there to help. What about the following? I am guessing that it will be faster, yet to try on the big dataset:   bysort mpg rep78: egen sum_m_r_price = sum(price)
bysort mpg rep78: egen count_m_r_price = count(price)

bysort mpg: egen sum_r_price = sum(price)
bysort mpg: egen count_r_price = count(price)

gen b_wanted =  ( sum_r_price-sum_m_r_price )/ (count_r_price-count_m_r_price)